# Fibonacci Sphere with svg(images) instead of points

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a Fibonacci Sphere with a canvas like the following code, but instead of the same point showing everywhere I want to show different images, possibly svgs like logos and other images. I've done some research in google like visiting codepen and other places but couldn't find anything that worked. I imagine it would be something like the one in this website [here](https://jacekjeznach.com/about). Any idea on how to approach this?

```js
var cant = 100;
var offset = 2 / cant;
var increment = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var i;
var circle;

//---Build the elements
for(i = 0; i < cant; i++){
  
  circle = document.createElement("div");
  circle.className = "point";
  circle.setAttribute("data-index", i);
  
  canvas.appendChild(circle);
  
};

//---Apply transformations to points
function updatePoints(evt){
  
  var x, y, z, r, a, scale, opacity, point, style;
  
  var angle = (evt) ? (-evt.pageX / 4) * Math.PI / 180 : 0;
  
  for(i = 0; i < cant; i++){

    y = (i * offset - 1) + (offset / 2);
    r = Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(y, 2));
    a = ((i + 1) % cant) * increment + angle;
    x = Math.cos(a) * r;
    z = Math.sin(a) * r;

    scale = Math.round(z * 20000) / 100;
    opacity = (1 + z) / 1.5;
    
    style = "translate3d(" + (125 + x * 100) + "px, " + (125 + y * 100) + "px, " + scale + "px)";
    
    point = canvas.querySelectorAll("[data-index='" + i +"']");    
    point[0].style.WebkitTransform = style;
    point[0].style.msTransform = style;
    point[0].style.transform = style;
    point[0].style.opacity = opacity;

  }
  
}

//---Update the points at start
updatePoints();

//---Update the points on mouse move
document.addEventListener("mousemove", updatePoints);
```

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body{
  background-color: #232B2B;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#canvas{
  height: 250vh;
  margin: 0 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 250vh;
}

.point{
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  
</div>
```

Any help would be most helpful.

Comment: Cool sphere math. That's not a `canvas`. It's a div with `id='canvas'` that uses `Element.style.transform`. You can use `Element.style.background = 'url("yourSVGpath.svg#svgId")';`. Also.... since your points are created on the movement of the mouse, your design is processor intensive. Draw your sphere first, then rotate it. Don't draw it on every mouse movement. Those things add up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue using the `createElement` method.

I added this, to show a random image (from picsum) for each dot:

```
// Create a new img element
img = document.createElement('img');
// Add the src to each img element. 
//Here using the iterator variable to 
//change the id of the photo we are retrieving
img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/' + i +'/20/20'
// Append the img to the div
circle.appendChild(img);
```

And I made the circles a bit larger in the CSS (20px) so you can see it.

If you want specific images, you could create an array inside your JS, or pull from a folder on your server.

```js
var cant = 100;
var offset = 2 / cant;
var increment = Math.PI * (3 - Math.sqrt(5));
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

var i;
var circle;

//---Build the elements
for(i = 0; i < cant; i++){
  
  circle = document.createElement("div");
  img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = 'https://picsum.photos/id/' + i +'/20/20'
  circle.appendChild(img);
  circle.className = "point";
  circle.setAttribute("data-index", i);
  
  canvas.appendChild(circle);
  
};

//---Apply transformations to points
function updatePoints(evt){
  
  var x, y, z, r, a, scale, opacity, point, style;
  
  var angle = (evt) ? (-evt.pageX / 4) * Math.PI / 180 : 0;
  
  for(i = 0; i < cant; i++){

    y = (i * offset - 1) + (offset / 2);
    r = Math.sqrt(1 - Math.pow(y, 2));
    a = ((i + 1) % cant) * increment + angle;
    x = Math.cos(a) * r;
    z = Math.sin(a) * r;

    scale = Math.round(z * 20000) / 100;
    opacity = (1 + z) / 1.5;
    
    style = "translate3d(" + (125 + x * 100) + "px, " + (125 + y * 100) + "px, " + scale + "px)";
    
    point = canvas.querySelectorAll("[data-index='" + i +"']");    
    point[0].style.WebkitTransform = style;
    point[0].style.msTransform = style;
    point[0].style.transform = style;
    point[0].style.opacity = opacity;

  }
  
}

//---Update the points at start
updatePoints();

//---Update the points on mouse move
document.addEventListener("mousemove", updatePoints);
```

```css
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body{
  background-color: #232B2B;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#canvas{
  height: 250vh;
  margin: 0 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 250vh;
}

.point{
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, but not SVG.

Comment: @StackSlave _possibly svgs like logos and other images_ from the original question. I made the assumption that `other images` meant images (gif, jpg, png). I can certainly update for SVGs. But even then, it would be the same process, since you could use the `src` attribute to pull SVGs instead.

Comment: Yeah. I'm the one that gave you the points.

Comment: It's all good! I would also assume if OP wanted to use logos, they wouldn't be creating the SVGs. Thanks!